# Already defined in Main.obj c++

Tags: c++, enums

I'm trying to create an enum and an array to represent the array with string values like this:

```
#ifndef fruits_H
#define fruits_H

enum fruits { apples,oranges,pears };
const char *fruits_str[]={ "apples","oranges","pears" };

#endif
```

from [here](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/437852-c-enum-names-as-strings/)

so putting this in a header causes me to get an "already defined in Main.obj"

why? I did used #ifndef and also it happens only for array types.

EDIT:

I know that I can solve it by moving it to the cpp, but I don't want to.
I need them both in the same file, editing them at the same time.

Comment: You are including this header in multiple implementation files, correct?

Comment: Are you including this header in multiple files?  THe #ifndef would be processed for EACH file separately.  Take the data declarations out of it.

Comment: Yes, both in the Main.cpp and class.cpp (assuming this is class.h)

Comment: @vladp, well that is your problem.  Not a good idea to put data creation in a header file like this.  move to main.cpp and declare "extern" in other file, or encapulate in a class method to return the values.

Comment: It would have compiled fine if it was an `array` instead of an `array of pointers` because `const` provides internal linkage in `C++`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change it to `const char* const fruits_str[]={ "apples","oranges","pears" };`